# Search html elements by phrase

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a simply html view:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input id="summaryText" type="text" name="Summary" placeholder="Summary"><br>
<input id="groupText" type="text" name="Groups" placeholder="Groups"><br>
<input id="searchButton" type="button" value="Search"><br>
<table>
    <tr>
        <details>
            <summary><b>First Summary</b></summary>
            <ul>
                <details>
                    <summary><b>Groups</b></summary>
                    <ul>
                        <li>group A of First</li>
                        <li>group B of First</li>
                    </ul>
                </details>
                <details>
                    <summary><b>People</b></summary>
                    <ul>
                        <li>John</li>
                        <li>Mark</li>
                    </ul>
                </details>
            </ul>
        </details>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <details>
            <summary><b>Second Summary</b></summary>
            <ul>
                <details>
                    <summary><b>Groups</b></summary>
                    <ul>
                        <li>group A of Second</li>
                        <li>group B of Second</li>
                        <li>group C of Second</li>
                    </ul>
                </details>
                <details>
                    <summary><b>People</b></summary>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Alex</li>
                    </ul>
                </details>
            </ul>
        </details>
    </tr>
</table>
</body> 
</html>
```

I want to use `summaryText` and `groupText` to filter elements from page. It could be just something like `display:none`.

The first input `summaryText` should works as normal filter. It means that if `main summary` (from first details in every `tr` element) consists `String` from `summaryText` - it should be display for user (all elements from this `tr`), if doesn't consist - it should be hide for user (all elements from this `tr`).

The Second input should filter by `String` in `li` elements from `details` with summary `Groups`. If there is any `li` with `String` from `groupText` - all elements from this `tr` should be display and if doesnt - should be hide for user.

Is there any way to search for `details` element by `summary` and then get parent `tr` and show/hide it or just use any else solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following to get an array of all the elements belonging to a particular tag:

```
var array=document.getElementsByTagName("summary");
```

Iterate this array using a simple for loop and search for a string inside that tag.

```
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
   if(array[i].innerHTML.indexOf("word to search for") !== -1){
      //do something here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this logic:

```
$("*:not(body)").each(function() {
  if ($(this).html().indexOf("your phrase")>-1)
    // String is found, your code here
});
```